# Core Data App Shuts down at launch "Exited Voluntarily"

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I started a new project in SwiftUI and CoreData.  As soon as I added Transformable to on of the child record in my parent /child data model, the App launches and immediately shuts down.  When I try to use Previews, I now get Error Domain=FBProcessExit Code=1 "The process exited voluntarily." UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=voluntary, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The process exited voluntarily.}  on all views in the app.  Can anyone help me figure out how to debug this?

I am including the model code and the transformer in case this helps:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit


extension Event {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Event> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Event>(entityName: "Event")
    }

    @NSManaged public var cardFrontImage: UIImage?
    @NSManaged public var event: String?
    @NSManaged public var recipient: Recipient?

}

extension Event : Identifiable {

}
```

Tranformer code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ImageTransformer: ValueTransformer {
    
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return NSData.self
    }
    
    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        autoreleasepool{
            guard let data = value as? Data else {
                return nil
            }
            
            return UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
    
    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        autoreleasepool{
            guard let image = value as? UIImage else {
                return nil
            }
            
            return image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

And Where I set the Transformer in the @main

```
@main
struct HolidayCardApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    let context = PersistentCloudKitContainer.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    static let doInitialize: Void = {
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(ImageTransformer(), forName: NSValueTransformerName("ImageTransformer"))
        // register transformers here
    }()
    
    static func main() {
        HolidayCardApp.doInitialize
    }
  var body: some Scene {
  // CODE
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, by moving the Initialization of the ValueTransformer into my PersistentCloudKit Setup.